# PHP MSQL SELECT DATETIME REGARDLESS OF THE TIME

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$date = htmlentities($_POST['day']); 
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date); 
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); 
$act = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM log WHERE DATE(visit_hour)="'.$date.'" '); 
$act->execute();
```

the column is a datetime type.

This works perfectly when used in phpMyAdmin query. However, php processes the `date()` in the query to yield no results. Please help me out

Comment: Question about propramming should show code, not text describing code. Please add your current attempt so we can help you.

Comment: @catcon The code is in there, I fixed the formatting so it's more visible.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the query would work differently in PHP than phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Barmar: OP said he used php date() method, I don't see that code anywhere

Comment: I think he means that a query that uses MySQL `date()` works differently when executed from PHP.

Comment: @catcon He said "date() in the query"

Comment: Do you really have the date hard-coded in the query as you show, or are you generating it dynamically from input? The problem could be with how you're doing that.

Comment: @Barmar, many thanks for the formatting. I'm generating the date from an input. I've converted it to string to easy presentation. Many thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in the code that generates the date, show that code and some sample input.

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlentities()`? That should only be used when you're displaying data on a web page, to prevent characters like `<>` from being treated as HTML tags.

Comment: Do you see the expected date if you do `var_dump($date);`?

Comment: @Barmar, I used the htmlentities() to filter those special characters should a user enters them them in the input field just as you metioned

Comment: So if the user enters `<2020-11-08` you'll change it to `&lt;2020-11-08`. Why is that better for calling `strtotime()`?

Comment: With this, the user will get no data on feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224340/discussion-between-stev-k-and-barmar).

Comment: This is not the correct way to prepare queries